# Anaconda Python, how do I get values of groupby instead of just a print statement?

Tags: python, anaconda

So this is my code to group a Data Frame with 1000 rows and 20 columns. LABEL and B in this instance are columns.

```
value = df_sample.groupby(['LABEL','B']).size()
print(value)
```

Right now when I print the value I get this, which is fine, but I want to the individuals values like 26, 436, 53, 485 and make those values variables and use them elsewhere in the code. How do I do that? For instance, I want to make variable like label_0_b_0 so that when I call that variable, it returns 26. ALso, I think if it is 0, it does not show that, so is a way to tell that?

```
LABEL  B
0      0     26
       1    436
1      0     53
       1    485
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html
The following method probably does what you are asking for:

```
GroupBy.get_group(self, name[, obj])
"""
Construct DataFrame from group with provided name.
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you showed the dataframe so we know which values you're talking about.

But in any case you can always add a .reset_index() to turn it into a dataframe.

i.e.:

```
value = df_sample.groupby(['LABEL','B']).size().reset_index(name = 'size')
```

you can subsequently create new dataframes or vaariables based on the row and value

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the particular size values, you can use index values to access. For instance: to access `LABEL 0` and `B 0`, you can use `df[0,0]`. `df[0,0] returns 26`, `df[0,1] returns 436` for `LABEL 0 and B 1` and `so on`.

For labelling the column, `reset_index` can be used.